# Is there a way to directly access a C file from C# without a dll?

Tags: c#, c, mono, dllimport

I am making an application where there are lots of communications back and forth from C and C#, and I was wondering if there is any way to import C directly instead of exporting the c file to a DLL and importing that in my C# code.

#### Example:

(C)

```
void myFunction() {
}
```

(C#)

```
#include "myFile.c"

...

myFunction();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it standalone piece of code you want to use? .NET managed C++ compiler (/clr option) may be an answer...

Comment: Hi @AlexeiLevenkov, at first your suggestion looked great. But then I noticed, wouldn't OP need to compile a managed DLL anyway? As the Visual/.NET C++ file would not be able to sit in the same c# Project, right?

Comment: You have cancelled out the easiest and most direct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Host the C code in the same process as your C# code. This will require a DLL, either managed or unmanaged.
2. Host the C code in an external process. This will involve inter process communication, for instance COM.

Of these two, the former is surely much simpler.

Comment: Thanks! I guess there is no way to get around dlls if you're a noob like me :{

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the need of a DLL is that C# is part of the dot-net framework and therefore is probably being run by a runtime intepreter.  C code is not.  So, the C code needs to be packaged into a DLL that the C# runtime system can load.

*(Conceptually, the situation is actually very similar to that of many other language systems that are managed at runtime by some kind of interpreter.)*

Comment: There isn't a runtime interpreter. In any case this doesn't really answer the question. It can perfectly well be done without putting the C code in a dll loaded into the C# project. That's what was asked. Of course, it's not convenient to do that, but that's what the asker is actually asking.